# Nested elements firing parent's event even after stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I have an anchor tag(parent) containing an image(child) and a span(child). There is a dropdown div which i want to display when a user `mouseover` on the anchor tag.

That dropdown should hide when the user mouseover **on that anchor tag second time**.

I added `mouseover` event on the anchor tag to `toggle` the dropdown. But it's not working. I even added `stopPropogation()` on the child elements.

When i `mouseover` on the anchor tag, dropdown is shown. But then if i move mouse on the `span` or `div`, dropdown hides.

Here's the working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btmxf911/2/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#header-cart" id="custom_headercart" class="skip-link skip-cart" style="border: 1px solid black">    
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTClkntD56hOwVYr-e1blK4kXVusYujzM-ErrlL6QhonsYjqdK" alt="" width=18>
    <span>12</span>
 </a>

<div id="dropdown_div" style="display: none">
    Dropdown div content
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery

```
$("#custom_headercart").on("mouseover", function(){
    $("#dropdown_div").toggle();
})

$j("#custom_headercart span").mouseover(function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$j("#custom_headercart img").mouseover(function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Edit:** Dropdown should show and hide on alternate `mouseover`. Like if i `mouseover` the first time, it should show the dropdown. Then if i move out(dropdown shouldn't hide) and `mouseover` again, then it should hide.

Comment: Please add your code direct;y into to your question (you can use the edit link to paste it in).  Questions that rely only on external references to code are considered "off-topic" here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Stopping propagation on child elements will prevent the event from reaching the parent element.  It sounds like you're doing the opposite of what you want.

Comment: added html and jquery

Comment: use `css` http://jsfiddle.net/btmxf911/3/

Comment: if you want to keep the dropdown visible on hover http://jsfiddle.net/btmxf911/4/

Comment: It's because your div needs to be a child of the cart: http://jsfiddle.net/btmxf911/5/

Comment: @all Dropdown should hide when i mouseover on anchor second time. Not on mouseleave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. That way you don't need to prevent the child elements from propagating.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btmxf911/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the stop propagation to the parent , apply it to the child as it prevents "`event bubbling`" not "`Event capturing`"